# Synergy (ERROR: cannot read configuration)

Tags: windows-7, synergy

My Synergy server is failing to launch, with the following errors:

> [2015-12-02T10:55:48] INFO: activeDesktop:Default
>
> [2015-12-02T10:55:48] ERROR: cannot read configuration
> "C:/Users/AL/AppData/Local/Temp/qt_temp.gq1960": read error: line 2:
> invalid character 0xffffffcf synergys.exe: no configuration available
>
> [2015-12-02T10:55:49] ERROR: failed to launch, error: process
> immediately stopped

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have an error in your configuration file, at line 2.

Comment: Help edit this error !?

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case Synergy would create another similarly named file a shortly afterward and repeat until I closed Synergy.  I tried to correct the error in this "configuration file" by editing the file.  Synergy would just create a similar file, with the same error, and report the same error. In my case the problem seemed to be related to the "Hotkeys" configuration feature, and when I deleted all the Hotkeys, the problem went away.  I suspect there is a "real" configuration file, which the application copies (see the error messages above) and then tries to parse.